# How to find this limit in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the following four expressions evaluated in Mathematica.

```
Assuming[Element[t3, Reals] & u1 > 0, FullSimplify[Limit[(E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 - Sqrt[E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 + E^(2*t1 + t3)*u1 + E^(2*t1 + 2*t3)*u1^2])/(-1 + E^t1), t1 -> 0, 
    Direction -> -1]]]

Assuming[Element[t3, Reals] & u1 > 0, FullSimplify[(E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 - Sqrt[E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 + E^(2*t1 + t3)*u1 + E^(2*t1 + 2*t3)*u1^2])/(-1 + E^t1)]]

Assuming[Element[t3, Reals] & u1 > 0, FullSimplify[Limit[FullSimplify[(E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 - Sqrt[E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 + E^(2*t1 + t3)*u1 + E^(2*t1 + 2*t3)*u1^2])/(-1 + E^t1)], 
    t1 -> 0, Direction -> -1]]]

N[(E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 - Sqrt[E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 + E^(2*t1 + t3)*u1 + E^(2*t1 + 2*t3)*u1^2])/(-1 + E^t1) /. {t1 -> 0.0001, t3 -> 0.5, u1 -> 10, N1 -> 10}]
```

The first expression tries to evaluate a limit of something and evaluates to

DirectedInfinity[1 + E^t3* u1 - Sqrt[(1 + E^t3* u1)^2]]

The second expression is just asking Mathematica to try to simplify the expression of which I am trying to find the limit, which it does. Then, the third expression asks it to find the same limit as the first expression but using the simplified expression. It evaluates to

(1 + (1 + E^t3* u1)/Sqrt[(1 + E^t3* u1)^2])^(-1)

This obviously should be 0.5 when t3 is real and u1>0, but somehow Mathematica doesn't simplify it. The fourth expression just numerically evaluates the limit by using t1=0.0001 and some values for the other variables. The result is 0.500001.
So, it looks like the limit should be 0.5. That's what I intuitively expect the answer to be from the application where the problem originally came from. But, why can't Mathematica evaluate that original limit correctly? Thanks.

Comment: `And` is entered as `&&` rather than `&`. Use `Assuming[Element[t3, Reals] && u1 > 0, Limit[(E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 - Sqrt[E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 + E^(2*t1 + t3)*u1 + E^(2*t1 + 2*t3)*u1^2])/(-1 + E^t1), t1 -> 0, Direction -> -1]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it can't do everything at once, but it works for me if I break it into pieces:

Define the expression

```
expr1 = (E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 - 
     Sqrt[E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 + E^(2*t1 + t3)*u1 + 
       E^(2*t1 + 2*t3)*u1^2])/(-1 + E^t1) // Simplify
```

Make assumptions

```
$Assumptions = t3 \[Element] Reals && u1 > 0
```

Then

```
Limit[expr1, t1 -> 0]
(*1/2*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Series`, one obtains

```
Series[(E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 - 
Sqrt[E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 + E^(2*t1 + t3)*u1 + 
  E^(2*t1 + 2*t3)*u1^2])/(-1 + E^t1), {t1, 0, 1}]
```

> $$ \frac{e^{\text{t3}} \text{u1}-\sqrt{\left(e^{\text{t3}} \text{u1}+1\right)^2}+1}{\text{t1}}+\frac{\left(e^{\text{t3}} \text{u1}+1\right) \left(\sqrt{\left(e^{\text{t3}} \text{u1}+1\right)^2}-e^{\text{t3}} \text{u1}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\left(e^{\text{t3}} \text{u1}+1\right)^2}}+\frac{\text{t1} \left(-2 e^{2 \text{t3}} \text{u1}^2-4 e^{\text{t3}} \text{u1}+2 e^{\text{t3}} \text{u1} \sqrt{\left(e^{\text{t3}} \text{u1}+1\right)^2}+2 \sqrt{\left(e^{\text{t3}} \text{u1}+1\right)^2}+1\right)}{24 \sqrt{\left(e^{\text{t3}} \text{u1}+1\right)^2}}+O\left(\text{t1}^2\right) $$

and

```
Series[(E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 - 
Sqrt[E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 + E^(2*t1 + t3)*u1 + 
  E^(2*t1 + 2*t3)*u1^2])/(-1 + E^t1), {t1, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> 1 + E^t3 u1 > 0]
```

> $$O\left(\text{t1}^2\right)+\frac{\text{t1}}{8 \left(e^{\text{t3}} \text{u1}+1\right)}+\frac{1}{2} $$

and

```
Limit[(E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 - 
Sqrt[E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 + E^(2*t1 + t3)*u1 + 
  E^(2*t1 + 2*t3)*u1^2])/(-1 + E^t1), t1 -> 0, 
 Assumptions -> 1 + E^t3 u1 > 0]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[1/2, u1*(2*E^t3 + u1*Re[E^(2*t3)]) >-1`

Comment: Finally, `Limit[(E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 - 
    Sqrt[E^t1 + E^(t1 + t3)*u1 + E^(2*t1 + t3)*u1 + 
      E^(2*t1 + 2*t3)*u1^2])/(-1 + E^t1), t1 -> 0, 
 Assumptions -> 
  u1*(2*E^t3 + u1*Re[E^(2*t3)]) > -1 && 
   Sqrt[(1 + E^t3 u1)^2] == 1 + E^t3 u1]` produces `1/2`.